# How to read date from form in play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I have `Date expirationDate` field in my class. I also have select dropdown menu in my form with day/month/year

```
<select class="form-control" value="@form("day")" >
            <option>dd</option>
            @for(a <- 1 to 31) {
            <option>@a</option>
            }
</select>
<select class="form-control" value="@form("month")" >
            <option>mm</option>
            @for(a <- 1 to 12) {
            <option>@a</option>
            }
</select>
<select class="form-control" value="@form("year")" >
            <option>yyyy</option>
            @for(a <- 2014 to 2100) {
            <option>@a</option>
            }
</select>
```

How can i bind this data to `java.util.Date` type in controller? More specifically

```
public static Result createScenarioPOST() throws ParseException {
    User user=User.find
            .where().eq("email", session("email")).findUnique();

    Form<Creation> createForm = Form.form(Creation.class)
            .bindFromRequest();
    if (createForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(createScenario.render(createForm, user));
    } else {
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use only one input like https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here comes from having separate input fields for day/month/year fields. Since Play's `Form`s map to individual values, you cannot use them to map to a single value.

Use a `Form` to map (and validate!) the individual values, then construct the `Date` the way you normally would create a `Date`.

An easier way to do this is by having the date be a single form value, for example by using an `<input type="date">` input field. If your really must have separate fields and really want to bind it to a single field, you could consider using JavaScript to concatenate the separate fields into a single value on form submit.

Comment: Also, consider using Joda Time, it's a lot better than Java's built-in stuff, and Play supports it.